# mbedtls with PSK resulting in error

Tags: openssl, cryptography, mbedtls

I'm trying to use PSK with mbedtls library combined with SGX. Without PSK the connection works fine as it should.

Here is the relevant client side code:

```
mbedtls_entropy_context entropy;
mbedtls_ctr_drbg_context ctr_drbg;
mbedtls_ssl_context ssl;
mbedtls_ssl_config conf;
mbedtls_x509_crt cacert;

mbedtls_net_init(&server_fd);
mbedtls_ssl_init(&ssl);
mbedtls_ssl_config_init(&conf);
mbedtls_x509_crt_init(&cacert);
mbedtls_ctr_drbg_init(&ctr_drbg);


mbedtls_entropy_init( &entropy );
if ((mbedtls_ctr_drbg_seed(&ctr_drbg, mbedtls_entropy_func, &entropy, (const unsigned char*) pers, strlen(pers))) != 0) {
    mbedtls_printf( " failed\n  ! mbedtls_ctr_drbg_seed returned %d\n", ret );
    ret = -1;
    break;
}

ret = mbedtls_x509_crt_parse(&cacert, (const unsigned char *) mbedtls_crt, mbedtls_crt_len);

if ((ret = mbedtls_net_connect(&server_fd, SERVER_NAME, SERVER_PORT, MBEDTLS_NET_PROTO_TCP )) != 0) {
    mbedtls_printf( " failed\n  ! mbedtls_net_connect returned %d\n\n", ret );
    break;
}

if ((ret = mbedtls_ssl_config_defaults(&conf,
                                       MBEDTLS_SSL_IS_CLIENT,
                                       MBEDTLS_SSL_TRANSPORT_STREAM,
                                       MBEDTLS_SSL_PRESET_DEFAULT)) != 0 )
{
    mbedtls_printf( " failed\n  ! mbedtls_ssl_config_defaults returned %d\n\n", ret );
    break;
}

mbedtls_ssl_conf_authmode( &conf, MBEDTLS_SSL_VERIFY_OPTIONAL );
mbedtls_ssl_conf_ca_chain( &conf, &cacert, NULL );
mbedtls_ssl_conf_rng( &conf, mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random, &ctr_drbg );
mbedtls_ssl_conf_dbg( &conf, my_debug, NULL );
mbedtls_ssl_conf_verify( &conf, my_verify, NULL );

const unsigned char psk_key[] = {
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
    0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f
};
size_t psk_len = sizeof( psk_key );
const char psk_id[] = "Client_identity";

if ((ret = mbedtls_ssl_conf_psk(&conf, psk_key, psk_len,
                                (const unsigned char *) psk_id,
                                strlen(psk_id))) != 0 )
{
    mbedtls_printf( "  mbedtls_ssl_conf_psk returned %d\n\n", ret );
    break;
}



if( ( ret = mbedtls_ssl_setup( &ssl, &conf ) ) != 0 )
{
    mbedtls_printf( " failed\n  ! mbedtls_ssl_setup returned %d\n\n", ret );
    break;
}

if( ( ret = mbedtls_ssl_set_hostname( &ssl, "mbed TLS Server 1" ) ) != 0 )
{
    mbedtls_printf( " failed\n  ! mbedtls_ssl_set_hostname returned %d\n\n", ret );
    break;
}

mbedtls_ssl_set_bio( &ssl, &server_fd, mbedtls_net_send, mbedtls_net_recv, NULL );

mbedtls_printf( " ok\n" );
mbedtls_printf( "  . Performing the SSL/TLS handshake..." );

while ((ret = mbedtls_ssl_handshake(&ssl)) != 0) {
    if (ret != MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_WANT_READ && ret != MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_WANT_WRITE) {
        mbedtls_printf( " failed\n  ! mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned -0x%x\n\n", -ret);
        break;
    }
}


....
```

I have the openssl test server running with:

```
 openssl s_server -accept 4433 -cert server.pem -psk 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f -psk_hint Client_identity -cipher PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA -debug
```

The server receives the connection and exchanges the PSK messages as well, but
at the decryption point I receive the following error:

```
 error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac:s3_pkt.c:532:
```

I have also tried to change the `-cipher PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA` to a different cipher but still the same error.
When omitting the cipher entirely the connection works but no PSK is performed!?

Answer (score 2):

After several attempts, I managed to get to the root cause of this issue. The reason for the failure, is implied from the following log in openssl s_server logs(I used -debug -tlsextdebug):

> created PSK len=15

Which is originated from [openssl code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/s_client.c#L167)
However, the key you are using is 16 bytes. 
when I changed the psk to "010102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f" , the TLS connection worked, with the following log:

> created PSK len=16

I believe the root cause for this failure is within [`OPENSSL_hexstr2buf()` implementation](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/s_client.c#L149), which ignores the most significant zeros, thus returning a false length of the key.